# Create table whose columns properties are rows of another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle11g, relational-database

First of all please do not mark this as duplicate as I am not asking for selecting but for a new table creation. To be more clear I have a table like:

```
CREATE  TABLE Attributes (
   Col_Name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
   Col_type VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
   Col_ID   VARCHAR(45) NULL 
);

Col_Name    |   Col_type|   Col_ID
-----------------------------------------------
C1          T1      1
C2          T2      2
```

and I want to end up having something like this:

```
C1(T1)| C2(T2)
----------------
Val      Val
```

Thank you

Comment: I have searched a little but everything was related to perform some special "select" but I need to have a new table here, if you can please tell me what are the possibilities of achieving this because I understand that this might not be straightforward. thank you

Comment: `SELECT Col_Name, Col_Type, Col_ID FROM Attributes` Then process it in your programming language and put it into a HashTable, for example.

Comment: Can you give me a small example in java please? Thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: I see bad logic in your idea. What happiness if you put more than two rows in Attributes? like 10 or 100? How you should form your column names then? I can write Procedure for you by your example,but it is very bad logic.

Comment: I understand but I have to have an attribute table and another table that will use as attribute columns the rows of the first. If you have another idea please share with me :)

Comment: If you have a limited number of column types, like 10, it might be better to have a separate table for each column type.

Comment: Yes but the idea behind is that the system should be flexible and allow the user to add other attributes as well. So that is why I thought about adding rows in an attribute table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These procedures is in Oracle, One of these should fit your problem. This will create table with as many columns as there is rows.

Attribute as attribute and fixed column type:

```
DECLARE
  lc_string VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT Col_Name, Col_type FROM Attributes ORDER BY Col_ID) LOOP
    lc_string := lc_string||c1.Col_Name||'_'||c1.Col_type||'_'||' VARCHAR2(100), ';
  END LOOP;
  lc_string := SUBSTR(lc_string,0,(LENGTH(lc_string)-2));
  lc_string := 'CREATE TABLE some_name ('||lc_string||')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lc_string; 
END;
/
```

Attribute as column type:

```
DECLARE
  lc_string VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT Col_Name, Col_type FROM Attributes ORDER BY Col_ID) LOOP
    lc_string := lc_string||c1.Col_Name||' '||c1.Col_type||', ';
  END LOOP;
  lc_string := SUBSTR(lc_string,0,(LENGTH(lc_string)-2));
  lc_string := 'CREATE TABLE some_name ('||lc_string||')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lc_string; 
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but Oracle keeps on telling me that 'IMMEDIATE' is unknown Command..

Comment: try to put on screen lc_string, and look if it is right formated (all ', ()' is in place). The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is standart PL/SQL statement in Oracle.

Comment: maybe something is going wrong with my Oracle.. however I think your answer is the best so I am going to accept this :)

Comment: Put dbms_output.put_line(lc_string); before or insted EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Then you will see if there is nothing wrong with your string. What kind of error are you geting?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is for a temp table it is concerning that you would be creating tables often enough for this to be worthwhile.

Anyway, the following basic SQL would create the create  query for you:-

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sometable` (, ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', Col_Name, '` ', Col_type) ORDER BY Col_ID SEPARATOR ','), ");")
FROM Attributes
```

(assuming MySQL rather than Oracle)

A bit of a play combining my SQL with DARK_As proc examples:-

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sometable` (, ' || (LISTAGG('`' || Col_Name || '` ' || Col_type, ',') WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY Col_ID) || ');') AS CreateCommand FROM Attributes) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c1.CreateCommand;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Please note that this is not tested (and you might require a GROUP BY clause for the table, should the Attributes table contain the descriptions of multiple tables).

Comment: I think you get a ',' in last column yust before ')', which may rise error.

Comment: You shouldn't do, as the commas are added by the group_concat so will only be used to separate fields.. Unless I have made a typo somewhere

Comment: sir I kept on trying but all I am getting is a select result and no table is being created, is there any mistake? thank you anyway

Comment: The select result should be a create statement which you then need to execute.

Comment: Possible you could combine my SQL statement with the basic procedures from DARK_A to do the job. Seems Oracle now supports a function called LISTAGG which is pretty much equivalent to GROUP_CONCAT - http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515 - so this should be fairly easy (afraid I don't use Oracle these days and have no development environment for it so I will try an knock something up but not sure it will be correct)

Comment: I am going to fix my Oracle first cause it seems to have some problems, thank you again :)